# AWS Lambda: Will Lambda incur cost if it is waiting for File event of Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an Amazon S3 bucket to which I am loading files. After loading files, I create a specific file based on which the Lambda function will trigger. So while the Lambda function is waiting for the file to materialize in Amazon S3, will it incur cost? I am new starting out in AWS, this question might seem naïve but please do help.

Comment: You say the lambda will trigger. So no, it's not waiting around. S3 will invoke your lambda when that event of interest occurs.

Comment: Just to clarify, the lambda will only be triggered once this specific file is created, right? How this "specific" file is created? I can think of two scenarios.

1) Lambda function only triggered once this "specific" file is created. In this scenario there will be no lambda cost will occured for "waiting" since the lambda cost calculated on the number of requests made and execution time. 

2) Lambda creates the "specific" file. Here, Yes cost will occur as I stated before lambda cost calculated on the number of requests made and execution time.